# Boot problems with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have been running Ubuntu for several years with success.  I started with 12.04 LTS, then moved up to 14.04 LTS.  I updated to 16.04 LTS only a few days ago.  Since then I've had trouble getting the desktop to boot-up.

GRUB boots into Windows just fine.  If I boot to Windows, then re-boot into Ubuntu, it'll boot just fine.  The other way I can boot into Ubuntu successfully, is to boot using 'advanced options>Ubuntu' in GRUB.  Ubuntu will eventually boot up this way.  Something is wrong, but I'm not a Linux command line expert. I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Extra info:

- using - Dell Optiplex 745
- Windows version - XP
- internet is oddly slow

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: Also, Windows XP reached the end of its support life 2 years ago and doesn't even receive security fixes since then. You're leading a dangerous life if you have anything on there that might be of value to someone trying steal your identity (or simply trash your data).

Comment: Well, I struggled thru installing and running boot-repair.  I turned off the Hibernate feature in Windows XP,  and Canonical updated Ubuntu 16.04.  The machine now seems to boot just fine, but I have no idea what fixed it.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure Hibernate is turned off in Windows XP. If *hiberfil.sys* is present, boot aborts without explanation.